# Send events infos to Einstein bot using api

Tags: salesforce, chatbot, apex, apex-code, salesforce-einstein

I want to ask you how can we send infos  from an apex trigger listner to Einstein bot when a record is inserted or updated

I tried using Einstein bot api but I got confused and I don't know the exact steps